# CSRF Protection with tokens in meta tag - why can't it be stolen?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

A recommendation for being able to include a csrf prevention token in ajax calls is to include them as a meta tag in your page, which can then be accessed and included in the header.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html

How is this not exploitable? For example if example.com included the csrf token in a meta tag, could I not just create a malicious site that has some javascript that will make a call to example.com, and then parse the response, find the meta tag, and then inject the token value into my malicious page form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSRF token is unique to each session. Once it's generated it is only valid for use once, tied to a specific session.

A malicious person could get one generated, but it would be specific to their browser session. In short, they would only use it to be able to exploit themselves.

As for generating an attack through JavaScript, it's really an issue separate from CSRF. CSRF is an attack like [this one from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Example_and_characteristics):

```
<img src="http://bank.example.com/withdraw?account=Alice&amount=1000000&for=Mallory"/>
```

Protecting against malicious JavaScript is a different story. Sites protect themselves from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and other types of JavaScript injection by scrubbing user input, `iframe` sandboxing, and relying on the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

**TL;DR**

If you're running other people's untrusted JavaScript in your site, then you have bigger problems than CSRF.

Comment: I thought a csrf token is unique per session, so every request within a session would have the same token? Having rotating tokens wouldn't be very friendly for our end users who will often go back in their browser.

Comment: [There seems to be some debate](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request) about how often CSRF tokens should be refreshed, but I tend to agree that once per session/login should be OK. I glossed over your attack vector in the question though--I have updated my answer for clarity and hope this an acceptable answer now.

Answer (score 2):

A script running in Alice's browser at chuck.com cannot read carol.com's content due to the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy .

The script on chuck.com can POST to carol.com, but it cannot read and parse its content.